# How can I customize a search bar in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6.0

I am working on searchbar customization. I googled it, and I did not find an answer to my problem.

[image: Search your Match]

I used the following code to change background image:

```
 searchBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 [[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-magnifier"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I already used the code for getting subviews of searchbar, but it did not help. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed that you have a off-name image…is search-.png supposed to be named that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give file extension like sayings of user2277872 .

Answer (score 0):

Hi i did my searchbar issue using below code. its working fine.

```
 searchBar.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

searchBar.layer.cornerRadius=5;
searchBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:71/255.f green:71/255.f blue:67/255.f alpha:1];
searchBar.backgroundImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-block.png"];
UITextField *searchField;
NSUInteger numViews = [searchBar.subviews count];
for(int i = 0; i < numViews; i++)
{
    if([[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    { //conform?
        searchField = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
if(!(searchField == nil))
{
    searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [searchField setBackground: [UIImage imageNamed:@"search-block.png"]];//just add here gray image which you display in quetion
    [searchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
}
[[UISearchBar appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-magnifier"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```